# Chrome gives wrong element width

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mootools

I'm making a tooltip class in Mootools that depends on getting the width of the tooltip element to centre it over the target.

It works nicely in all browsers except Chrome, which comes up with two wildly different numbers for the element width on each reload of the page. When I set a width of 100 and height 20 in the CSS, the Chrome web dev inspector shows the dimensions correctly. But when I refresh the page Chrome logs out a mad figure like 1904, and my element is positioned far away to the side.

I've tried using these different ways of getting the width, either hiding the tooltip with display:none or z-index:

- getDimensions()
- getSize()
- getStyle('width')
- element.offsetWidth

all with similar results. Can any kind person suggest a workaround, or tell me why Chrome is behaving in this way?

Thanks!
Fred

Here's my JS:

```
Tooltip = new Class({

    Implements: Events,
    Implements: Options,

    options: {
        target: '',                                 // Single element or array of elements
        tip: ''                                     // Element to show          
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.setOptions(options);
        this.setValues();
        this.attachEvents();
    },

    setValues: function() {     
        this.target = this.options.target;
        this.tip = this.options.tip;
        this.tip.setStyle('z-index', -1);                                                   // Hide tip element
        if (this.target == null || this.tip == null) return;                    // We don't have required elements, so return
        this.showing = false;
        this.tipMousedOver = false;
        this.tipDimensions = this.tip.getSize();            // Getting width
        console.log(this.tip);
        console.log(this.tipDimensions.x);
        console.log(this.tip.offsetWidth);

        this.tipFx = new Fx.Morph(this.tip, {
            duration: 350,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeIn,
            link: 'cancel',
            onComplete: function() {
                if (this.showing) this.showing = false;
                else this.showing = true;
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },

    attachEvents: function() {

        this.tip.addEvent('mouseenter', function(e) {
            this.tipMousedOver = true;
            document.removeEvents('click');
        }.bind(this));

        this.tip.addEvent('mouseleave', function(e) {
            document.addEvent('click', this.bodyClick.bind(this));  
        }.bind(this));

        if (typeOf(this.target) == 'element') {
            this.target.addEvent('click', this.toggleTip.bind(this));
        } else {
            this.target.each(function(item, index){
                item.addEvent('click', this.toggleTip.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
        }

    },

    toggleTip: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (!this.showing) {
            // HIdden, so show
            var posn = e.target.getPosition();
            var vPosn = posn.y;
            var hPosn = posn.x;
            var targetWidth = e.target.getSize().x;
            this.tip.setStyle('z-index', 1);
            this.tip.setStyle('top', vPosn - (this.tipDimensions.y + 10));
            this.tip.setStyle('left', (hPosn + targetWidth /2) - (this.tipDimensions.x / 2));       // Positions middle of tip over middle of target
            console.log('targetWidth: ' + targetWidth + ' tipDimensions.x: ' + this.tipDimensions.x);
            this.tipFx.start({'opacity': [0, 1]});
            document.addEvent('click', this.bodyClick.bind(this));
        } else {
            // Visible, so hide
            if (!this.tipMousedOver) {
                this.tipFx.start({'opacity': 0});
                this.tip.setStyle('z-index', 1);
                document.removeEvent('click', this.bodyClick);
            }       
        }
    },

    bodyClick: function(e) {
        this.tipFx.start({'opacity': 0});
        this.tip.setStyle('z-index', 1);
        document.removeEvents('click', this.bodyClick);
    }

});



window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    new Tooltip({
        target: $('comments-list').getElements('.shareLink'),
        tip: $('shareTip')
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="js/mootools-core-1.3.2-full-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mootools-more-1.3.2.1.js"></script>

<script src="comments_new_click.js"></script>

<link href="comments_new.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="comments-list">
        <!-- START COMMENT ITEM -->
        <li id="CommentKey-f8b1-45f2-b4f6-68ba740ca9c3" class="commentItem">
                <div class="commentTop clrd">
                    <span class="badges">
                        <img style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" src="" alt="" title="">
                        <img style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" src="" alt="" title="">
                    </span>
                    <a class="avatar" href="javascript:;" title="">
                        <img src="" alt="Photo of editor1">
                    </a>                
                    <a class="username" href="javascript:;" title="">And Finally</a>
                </div>
                <div class="commentBody clrd">

                    <div class="commentOver">
                        <div class="submDateAndTime">26 April 2011</div>
                    </div>                  

                    <div class="commentSide">
                        <div class="likeDislike">
                            <a class="pluck-like alreadyvoted" href="javascript:;" title="">Like</a>
                            <span class="pluck-score">00000</span>
                            <a class="pluck-dislike" href="javascript:;" title="">Dislike</a> 
                        </div>
                    </div>                  

                    <div class="commentText">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a sapien vitae enim sagittis sodales at sit amet leo. Aenean cursus euismod blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque vestibulum nisi id dui aliquet consequat. Nulla egestas tortor vel metus dapibus luctus. Nullam rhoncus ullamcorper lorem, non vehicula nulla euismod viverra. Morbi tempus dui ut ipsum interdum ut dapibus est venenatis. 
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="commentBottom clrd">

                    <div class="getReplies">
                        <a href="javascript:;" title="Show replies to this comment">See Replies</a>
                        <span>2</span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- To delete -->
                    <div style="display:block;clear:both;float:none;height:0"></div>

                </div>

                <!-- REPLIES -->
                <div id="nestedcommentslist-CommentKey:f8b1-45f2-b4f6-68ba740ca9c3" class="repliesWrapper"></div>
                <!-- END REPLIES -->

        </li>
        <!-- END COMMENT ITEM -->
                <!-- START COMMENT ITEM -->
        <li id="CommentKey-f8b1-45f2-b4f6-68ba740ca9c3" class="commentItem">
                <div class="commentTop clrd">
                    <span class="badges">
                        <img style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" src="http://z.x.co.uk/ver1.0/Content/images/store/5/6/3262-4af5-8654-ef59a25b24e1.Full.png" alt="" title="">
                        <img style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" src="http://z.x.co.uk/ver1.0/Content/images/store/5/6/3262-4af5-8654-ef59a25b24e1.Full.png" alt="" title="">
                    </span>
                    <a class="avatar" href="javascript:;" title="">
                        <img src="http://z.x.co.uk/ver1.0/Content/images/store/13/3/f175-45b8-931b-28619aadfd2a.Small.png" alt="Photo of editor1">
                    </a>                
                    <a class="username" href="javascript:;" title="">And Finally</a>
                </div>
                <div class="commentBody clrd">

                    <div class="commentOver">
                        <div class="submDateAndTime">26 April 2011</div>
                    </div>                      

                    <div class="commentText">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a sapien vitae enim sagittis sodales at sit amet leo. Aenean cursus euismod blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque vestibulum nisi id dui aliquet consequat. 
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="commentBottom clrd">

                        <div class="getReplies">
                            <a href="javascript:;" title="Show replies to this comment">See Replies</a>
                            <span>2</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="share">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="abuse" title="">Report abuse</a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="shareLink" title="">Share</a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- To delete -->
                        <div style="display:block;clear:both;float:none;height:0"></div>

                </div>
                <!-- REPLIES -->
                <div id="nestedcommentslist-CommentKey:f8b1-45f2-b4f6-68ba740ca9c3" class="repliesWrapper"></div>
                <!-- END REPLIES -->

        </li>
        <!-- END COMMENT ITEM -->
    </ul>

    <div id="shareTip" class="popup">Share and things</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

#comments-list {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.commentItem {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.avatar {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.avatar img {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
}

.commentTop {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 48px;
    background: #e8e8eb;
}

.username {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    height: 1em;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.badges {
    float: right;
}

.badges img {
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.commentBody {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #f3f2f2;
}

.commentText {
    margin-right: 75px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.commentOver {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 0 3px 10px 0;
}

.submDateAndTime {
    float: left;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.getReplies {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}

.getReplies a {
    background-color: #ED9430; /* Put elsewhere */
  background-image: url("http://z.x.co.uk/images/comments-wide.png");
  background-position: -508px -245px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 60px;
}

.getReplies span {
  background-image: url("http://z.x.co.uk/images/comments-wide.png");
  background-position: -569px -245px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 21px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 41px;
  line-height: 19px;
}

.commentBottom {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #f3f2f2;
}

.share {
    float: right;
}

.popup {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#shareTip {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

=======================================

## LATER

For anyone else coming across a similar problem, I found it went away when I measured the tip element right before showing it, instead of when the object's initialised. So I changed my reveal method to:

```
toggleTip: function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!this.showing) {
        // HIdden, so show
        var posn = e.target.getPosition();
        var targetPosnY = posn.y;
        var targetPosnX = posn.x;
        var targetWidth = e.target.getSize().x;
        var targetHeight = e.target.getSize().y;
        var tipSize = this.tip.getSize();
        var tipPosnY = targetPosnY - (tipSize.y + 10);
        var tipPosnX = targetPosnX - (targetWidth / 2);
        this.tip.setStyle('z-index', 1);
        this.tip.setPosition({x: tipPosnX, y: tipPosnY});
        this.tipFx.start({'opacity': 1});
        document.addEvent('click', this.bodyClick.bind(this));
    } else {
        // Visible, so hide
        if (!this.tipMousedOver) {
            this.tipFx.start({'opacity': 0});
            this.tip.setStyle('z-index', 1);
            document.removeEvent('click', this.bodyClick);
        }       
    }
},
```

I also found that setPosition() is a more reliable way of positioning the element than setStyle().

Comment: are you - per chance - hiding the tip initially and then bringing it in from the dom hidden? this will not work. what you can do is - bring it out of the dom, embed in a proxy temp div off-screen, measure it correctly and get started.

Comment: Thanks again Dimitar! Interesting that canary behaves differently. I was on Chrome 11. I was initially hiding the tip with z-index -1. I've found that if I measure the element just before using I get the correct size every time.

Answer (score 2):

If you target the recent browsers only you can use `window.getComputedStyle` that returns all the css properties and values as they are painted on the screen.

Or just make a workaround for chrome using it.

Comment: Hi Mic, thanks for the tip - unfortunately getComputedStyle(this.tip).getPropertyValue('width') is giving me the same mad value as the other methods. This is really weird!

Comment: I don't think there is more proof needed that this element has really this size. I would look inside, what could give this width. Or in desperation, I would try to start from a blank page, and add elements and styles until I get the trouble.

Comment: Thanks Mic, good point. The size does seem to change intermittently in this browser for some unknown reason.